# Docusign API signHere tabs - not converting form fields into tabs

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to convert form fields with name `signature_1` and pre-filled value of `signature_1`.

I have been following this guide:
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs

Here is the issue that i have already written up on the problem: https://github.com/karmaradio/karma/issues/440

Docusign is creating signHere tabs on the contract, but always at the top left, so it isn't recognising the `signature_1` form field.

The object i send to docusign:

```
{
  emailBlurb: "Please sign the document using link provided.",
  emailSubject: "Karma document sign",
  documents: [
    {
      documentBase64: "encoded",
      documentId: 1,
      name: "jackum-mur-PAYE-1.pdf",
      transformPdfFields: "true"
     }
  ],
  recipients: {
    signers: [
      {
        email: "jmurphy+c@gmail.com",
        name: "jackum mur",
        recipientId: 1,
        routingOrder: 1,
        tabs: {
          signHereTabs: [
            {
              documentId: "1",
              pageNumber: "1",
              tabLabel: "signature_1"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        email: "jmurphy+first@gmail.com", 
        name: "first signee",
        recipientId: 2,
        routingOrder: 2,
        tabs: {
          signHereTabs: [
            {
              documentId: "1", 
              pageNumber: "1",
              tabLabel: "signature_2"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        email: "jmurphy+second@gmail.com", 
        name: "second signee",
        recipientId: 3, 
        routingOrder: 3,
        tabs: {
          signHereTabs: [
            {
              documentId: "1", 
              pageNumber: "1",
              tabLabel: "signature_3"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
  status: "sent"
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your PDF document.

Comment: Hi, I've had a response form docusign support team who have pointed me in the direction of composite templates. I will update this when I have played around with them a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After examining the [document](https://github.com/karmaradio/karma/files/1112852/p60-form.pdf) you have shared, the following json should covert the form fields appropriately. Looking at the convention of your Tab labels, it is not clear which tabs apply to a particular recipient. So I have manually mapped each tabLabel to a recipient. From my example you can move the tabs based on the correct recipient.

If you want similar tab types to automatically populate with the same data then  see [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/#automatically-populating-tabs)

Here is the [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request.

> POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

```
{
  "emailSubject": "Document with Form fields",
  "status": "sent",
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "document": {
        "documentBase64": "<Add the bas64 encoded document bytes here>",
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "p60-form.pdf",
        "transformPdfFields": "true"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "jmurphy+c@gmail.com",
                "name": "jackum mur",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "signature_1"
                    },
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "signature_1DocuSignSignHere"
                    }
                  ],
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "signature_1 Student Loan deductions",
                      "value" : "<Pre-Fill Tab Value here>"
                    },
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "Student Loan deductions",
                      "value" : "<Pre-Fill Tab Value here>"
                    },
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "PAYE reference",
                      "value" : "<Pre-Fill Tab Value here>"
                    },
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "Your employer's full name and address (including postcode",
                      "value" : "<Pre-Fill Tab Value here>"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "email": "jmurphy+first@gmail.com",
                "name": "first signee",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder": "2",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "signature_2"
                    },
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "signature_2 DocuSignSignHere"
                    }
                  ],
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "signature_2",
                      "value" : "<Pre-Fill Tab Value here>"
                    },
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "signature_2 Your employers full name and address including postcode",
                      "value" : "<Pre-Fill Tab Value here>"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "email": "jmurphy+second@gmail.com",
                "name": "second signee",
                "recipientId": "3",
                "routingOrder": "3",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "signature_3"
                    },
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "signature_3 DocuSignSignHere"
                    }
                  ],
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "signature_3 PAYE reference",
                      "value" : "<Pre-Fill Tab Value here>"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: But you just copied the answer from my issue. Which is good, but also a little strange :)